# NameError at / name 'detail' is not defined

Tags: python, django, url, nameerror

I have it defined in blog/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', list),
    (r'^archive/(?P\d{1,2}/$', list),
    (r'^\d{4}/d{1,2}/(?P.*)/$', detail),
    (r'^(?P\d{4})/(?P\d{1,2})/$', month),
    (r'^(?P\d{4})/$', year),
    (r'^category/$', category),
    (r'^category/(?P.*)/$', one_category),
    (r'^tag/$', tag),
    (r'^tag/(?P.*)/$', one_tag), )
```

this is in the main urls.py which should import these

```
 (r'^', include('republika.blog.urls')),
```

What is the problem?

~

Comment: You might want to consider giving your views more descriptive names - `list`, `detail`, `month` etc aren't great. Try `PostListView` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time, it'd help us to help you if you put the entire error into the question.

`NameError` means you are referencing a variable that has not been declared yet. In this case, it is `detail`.

I'm assuming `detail` is a function within your views? If that's the case, then you need to import your views. Put the following at the top of the file:

```
from views import *
```

Comment: Mistake I meant what would the whole error be because this is what I read.

Comment: @tamara if that was the only error you seen, then never mind. Usually, it comes with a stacktrace (source code, line numbers, etc). Did this work for you? You have to import your views.